# Interaction between View and ViewModel in Caliburn

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I'm a newcommer in Caliburn.

I have a couple of questions of MVVM and Caliburn.

1. How can a view invoke a method explicitly on a ViewModel? Caliburn invokes a ViewModel constructor first. So if it is, then where the instance is going to be contained? The code inside my View create a new instance at the moment (I need to invoke a method on ViewModel explicitly). But regarding that ViewModel should be instantiated already, this is silly.
2. How can I force a binding update on the UI thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caliburn.Micro has the concept of [actions](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions) to invoke verbs on your view models from the view. You can largely use conventions for this, so for example if you have a `Button` in your view with `x:Name="Save"`, then your `Save` method on the view model will be invoked when the `Button` is clicked.

You can always use explicit bindings to override the conventions, as well as providing your own conventions, and Caliburn.Micro also provides attached properties to associate view model methods to events in the view.

In terms of forcing a UI update, your view models will implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and Caliburn.Micro provides base implementations of this, including `PropertyChangedBase`, and `Screen` (which adds life cycle).

You can then use the Caliburn.Micro supplied helper method to invoke the `PropertyChanged` event. This is called `NotifyOfPropertyChange`, and it can take an expression lambda to specify which property to notify, rather than using a magic string.